# How to change the width of UIBarButtonItem with IB

Tags: interface-builder, xcode4.3, uibarbuttonitem

[image]

Some of you may think I am trolling. After all the pic shows clearly how to change it. With a cached. Changing that number from 37 do absolutely nothing. I can put 5,10, 50, 100, nothing changed.

I can change via code (haven't tried), but what's the point of having BarButtonItemSize field in IB if changing it doesn't change anything?

Answer (score 1):

UIBarButton width setting is not reflected in case of UINavigationBar. Here, width of UIBarButton adjusts itself based content length entered inside UIBarButton.

We can change UIBarButton width using IB and via code in case of UIToolBar.

Hope it helps.